# How to change glassfish application server default browser icon?

Tags: java, glassfish-3

Can we set a default browser-tab icon for applications running under glassfish server?

Comment: I think this is not possible, as far as I know, favicons are application scoped for Glassfish.

Comment: Me too so far... currently, i am setting it using the link tag from inside the application.

Comment: i got the solutions, please check this link [link] (https://www.coderanch.com/t/608780/glassfish/change-glassfish-application-server-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Simply add the favicon.ico icon to the docroot folder of glassfish, and restart.

If it did not work, then, you have to define the 'ico' extension mime-type in your default-web.xml glassfish file, this is done by adding the following code on the file:
    `<mime-mapping>
        <extension>ico</extension> 
        <mime-type>image/vnd.microsoft.icon</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>`